# How to make a multilevel condition rules in firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I My rules allow the user to read and write data if the localId, but I want to add a condition with email verification, I found a line of code on the Internet, but I don’t know how to add it correctly:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "$localId": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $localId",
      ".write": "auth.uid === $localId",
    }
  }
}
```

that is my rules

```json
".read": "auth != null && auth.token.email_verified"
```

and this is what I found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the condition `auth.token.email_verified == true` for `.read` and/or `.write`!

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "$localId": {
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $localId && auth.token.email_verified == true",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $localId && auth.token.email_verified == true",
    }
  }
}
```